# A question on the permutation of regular sequence of length two in commutative Noetherian ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If $(x,y)$ is a regular sequence in $R$ then I can show that the image of $x$ in $R/yR$ is not a zero divisor and $x S=S$ where $S=ann_R(y)$. Hence if $R$ is Noetherian and $x \in J(R)$ [the Jacobson radical of $R$],  then by Nakayama lemma , $S=0$ i.e. $y$ is not a zero divisor in $R$, so that $(y,x)$ is a regular sequence in $R$. My question is the following :

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring and $x \in R$  be a non-unit and not a zero divisor and such that $ y\in R$ and $(x,y)$ is Regular sequence in $R$ $\implies$ $(y,x)$ regular sequence in $R$. Then is it true that $x \in J(R)$ ?

Comment: What if $R=K[X]$ (or $R=K[X,Y]$ for a non-trivial example) and $x=X$?

Comment: Ah I see ... you are taking $R$ to be domain and $x\in R$ such that $R/xR$ is also a domain ... thanks

Comment: @user26857: Do you have any idea regarding what happens if neither $R$ nor $R/xR$ are domain ?